# Web scraping from Website having multiple page results

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I want the table of results of all the webpages for my selection from a website which returns multiple pages of results.

I tried the below code :
`enter code here`

```
    import pandas as pd
    dfs = []
    while i<27:
        url = " "
        dframe = pd.read_html(url.str(i), header=1)
        dfs.append(dframe[0].dropna(thresh=3))
        i=i+1
```

I expect the dframe to hold the records of all the 30 pages of results.
But im unable to run this ,it never stops running even after hours of running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in np.arange(26):
    url = "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;page="+str(i)+";spanmin1=01+Jan+2007;spanval1=span;template=results;type=bowling"
    df = pd.read_html(url)[2]
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df])
df2.drop(columns = 'Unnamed: 14', inplace = True)
```

This worked for me. When I browsed the website I only had 26 pages though. I also investigated a single page, and the table your looking at is the [2] df on the list that read_html returns.  Unnamed: 14 is the column with the arrow on the very right.

Comment: Will try this.That was another issue ,yes the table is at [2],but when i tried iterating for many pages I got irrelevant tables consisting of text.

Answer (score 0):

I've added and changed some stuff from your original code to make it work.

```py
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

i = 0
while i < 26:
    url = (
        "http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/stats/index.html?class=2;page="
        + str(i)
        + ";spanmin1=01+Jan+2007;spanval1=span;template=results;type=bowling"
    )
    dframe = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "engineTable"})
    dfs.append(dframe[2].drop(columns="Unnamed: 14"))
    i = i + 1

result = pd.concat(dfs)

print(result)
```